# Array ( [0] => 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, [1] => operable program or batch file. )

Tags: php, xampp, server, executable-jar

I am having trouble executing my jar file from my xampp virtual server. I am running xampp v3.2.1 and the jar works fine on the cmd line on my desktop, however not on the xampp server.

The output of my

```
exec(cmd, output)
```

is

```
Array ( [0] => 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, [1] => operable program or batch file. )
```

So I read into the xampp and it has tomcat installed but I still can't work out how to run the jar. Anyone have an idea? Thanks!

EDIT: So I found this https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=129309 however there is no php.ini file in here, maybe it has changed with newer versions

Comment: Do you have java installed?

Comment: It works fine on the cmd line on windows however when i try and call it on the php from the server it sends back the above error

Comment: Tomcat is a server for running Java servlets.  If you want to shell out to run a command line Java program then you need the command line Java program installed.

Comment: @Quentin Okay, so do you know how to install Java to the xampp server?

Comment: You don't. You install it on the OS. How you do that depends on the OS. Generally you would use your operating system's package manager.

Comment: @Quentin I have Java installed on my windows machine, but it does not run on the xampp server for some reason `C:\Users\peter>java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

C:\Users\peter>`

Comment: Then it is probably a path issue. Try putting the full path to java in your PHP.

Comment: @Quentin Here is the apache err log; `'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: You said that already. As I said, try using the full path (or change the collection of directories that the user your server is running as will look for executables in).

Comment: @Quentin I have tried many different paths and I am sure they are right and the current one is. It still doesn't change that it is not recognising java as a command. So it's saying that it wouldn't be able to run any Jar file, irrespective of the right/wrong file path

Comment: The error message says *'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command* — It can't find `java.exe`, it hasn't even got to the trying to handle the jar file.

Comment: @Quentin so how do i point it to the java.exe?

Comment: As I said, try using the full path (or change the collection of directories that the user your server is running as will look for executables in).